short movie, non American, about 3 witches flying on brooms. They were chasing each other I think
I remember seeing some kind of short movie on late one night in the early 90's or late 80's. There were 3 classically dressed and ugly (big long noses) witches flying on brooms in some woods. I think they were chasing something or each other. It was comedic I think.... They didn't speak except for some strange sounds. The video had a slight "stop action" look to it like it was put together frame by frame at times. I've never seen anything like it since but it's been in my head for decades. I really liked it. For some reason I think it was from Norway or something. Not sure why I think that, I might have watched the credits but it was in another language. If it was a music video I don't remember any music playing..

Are you sure they were in the woods and not in the city? (Asking because I know something very close except for that detail.)

Shot in the dark, but was it Hocus Pocus (1993) ? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107120/

Not Hocus Pocus. And Walt, you got me thinking.......maybe not in the woods......

OK, since it fits almost everything: this might be Gisèle Kérozène from 1990. Directed by Jan Kounen (who went on to direct feature films like Dobermann), it's about 3 witches who chase another witch through an urban landscape on flying broomsticks after she steals a statue they worship. It's all filmed in jittery stop-motion and the dialogue is mostly just comical sounds. Here is the entire short:




That's it!!!!! OMG. Wow. thanks.

Oh man! Saw this years ago at a film festival. Never thought I'd see it again. Very cool!

I am going to guess and say it is the 1922 silent Swedish film Haxan. 
This scene in particular stands out per your description




No, not it but what you posted was pretty good. lol. Never saw that before and I'm sharing with my Halloween friends. thanks!. It was definitely modern and in color, Late 1980's I think at the time I saw it.
